# Difference between AjaxLink and AjaxButton in Wicket

Tags: wicket

I just want to know the difference between AjaxLink and AjaxButton in Wicket and when it's preferable to use each one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AjaxButton submits a Form, i.e. all form components send their values to the server.

AjaxLink just notifies the server code that the user has clicked a link. It doesn't bring any data in the request by default.

Comment: Btw, if you want to create a link submitting form data, use AjaxSubmitLink.